# How to concatenate the results of two commands in R

Tags: r, syntax, command

How we can concatenate the results of two `R` commands `dim(filename)`  and `summary(filename)` for the filename in one output file as output.

I tried it but it is not correct:

```
output <- c(dim(filename), summary(filename)
OR 
output <- dim(filename); summary(filename)
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the `paste` to do that if you want a `string`  Looks like both of these functions can create different class of output.  It may be better to keep it in a `list` i.e. `list(dim(filename), summary(filename))`

Comment: @akrun Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `class` of two elements are different, it is better to place it in a `list` to preserve the `class`.

```
output <- list(dim(filename), summary(filename))
```